# Add ModelTransformer to dynamically created form field

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms, symfony-3.4

I have a form type with an dynamically created form field using an `FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA` as described in Symfony documentation:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/dynamic_form_modification.html

This works fine!

And I want to have a `ModelTransformer` on this field, because I have to transform the form input for the underlying entity. This is described here:
https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/data_transformers.html

This also works very fine - standalone. But not combined with the form modification!

This is an example:

```
<?php
namespace App\Form;

use App\Entity\Product;
use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\CallbackTransformer;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvent;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormEvents;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class ProductType extends AbstractType {

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name');

        $builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
            $product = $event->getData();
            $form = $event->getForm();

            if (!$product || null === $product->getId()) {
                $form->add('price');
            }
        });

        $builder->get('price')
            ->addModelTransformer(new CallbackTransformer(
                function ($value) {
                    // ToDo: Do transformation here
                    return $value;
                },
                function ($value) {
                    // ToDo: Do transformation here
                    return $value;
                }
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'data_class' => Product::class
        ));
    }

}
```

If I create and render this form I get an:

```
The child with the name "price" does not exist.
```

This sounds logical at this point - but is there any way to combine the `ModelTransformer` with the dynamically created field?

Answer (score 3):

The anonymous function binded to `PRE_SET_DATA` event is called after:

```
$builder->get('price')
```

That's the cause of the bug, but inside the anonymous function we can't add the model transformer either, because the `$builder` config is already processed at that moment.

As workaround you could to change the logic adding the `price` field first, then configure the transformer and remove it if needed on `PRE_SET_DATA` event:

```
$builder
    ->add('name')
    ->add('price')
;

$builder->get('price')->addModelTransformer(...);

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $product = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    // Inverting the condition
    if ($product && null !== $product->getId()) {
        $form->remove('price');
    }
});
```

---

Another workaround is to create your own `PriceType` adding the model transformers there:

```
class PriceType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->addModelTransformer(...);
    }

    //...
}
```

later, you'd use the same logic that before but setting the new *type*:

```
$builder->add('name');

$builder->addEventListener(FormEvents::PRE_SET_DATA, function (FormEvent $event) {
    $product = $event->getData();
    $form = $event->getForm();

    if (!$product || null === $product->getId()) {
        $form->add('price', PriceType::class);
    }
});
```

This one seems more elegant and intuitive.